# How can I upgrade version React?

Tags: reactjs

When I am trying to upgrade version React from **15.4.1** to **16.7.0**, there is a warning:

> It looks like Index is reassigning its own `this.props` while
>   rendering,This is not supported and can lead to confusing bugs.

[image]

What's wrong with this?

Comment: you need to show the relevant code in order for community to help

Comment: What’s the warning?

Comment: warning:It looks like Index is reassigning its own `this.props` while rendering,This is not supported and can lead to confusing bugs.  by the way ,  there is no warning when I update the react to 16.6.0. Only 16.7.0 will report an warning

Comment: thanks, I have uploaded the img with warning information

Comment: Could you please share the code of `Index`? Anyway, the issue seems to be that you are doing `this.props = ...` in the `render` function or on any function called within `render`.

Comment: inside `package.json` file, update the value corresponding to `react` as 16.7.0 and do `npm install`. I think this might work.